# Instanciar uma classe que herda uma classe interface

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface, instanciar-objeto

Tenho uma classe que herda muitas classes interfaces, e quero instanciá-la para usar apenas um método, como devo fazer? È possível fazer sem passar todos os parâmetros necessários?

```
public class PontoSituacaoService : IPontoSituacaoService,
        IMessageHandler<DespachoCreatedEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<OcorrenciaAssociadaEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<OcorrenciaDesassociadaEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<PartilharOcorrenciaEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<GrupoDespachosCreatedEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<AlteracaoEstadoOcorrencia, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<NotificacaoManualEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<OcorrenciaImportanciaModificadaEvento, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<AtualizarPOSITOcorrencia112, bool>,
        IMessageHandler<DanoHabitacionalCriadoEvento, bool>
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private readonly IRepository<PontoSituacao> _pontoSituacaoRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<SumarioPontoSituacao> _sumarioPontoSituacaoRepository;

    private readonly IOcorrenciaService _ocorrenciaService;
    private readonly ILookupService<TipoPontoSituacao> _tipoPontoSituacaoService;
    private readonly IModuloInterfacePortal _moduloInterfacePortal;

    private readonly ILookupService<TemplateNotificacaoSINOP> _templateService;

    private readonly IMessageBus _bus;

    public PontoSituacaoService(IRepository<PontoSituacao> pontoSituacaoRepository,
                IOcorrenciaService ocorrenciaService,
                ILookupService<TipoPontoSituacao> tipoPontoSituacaoService,
                IMessageBus bus,
                IModuloInterfacePortal moduloInterfacePortal,
                IRepository<SumarioPontoSituacao> sumarioPontoSituacaoRepository,
                ILookupService<TemplateNotificacaoSINOP> templateService)
    {
        _pontoSituacaoRepository = pontoSituacaoRepository;
        _sumarioPontoSituacaoRepository = sumarioPontoSituacaoRepository;
        _ocorrenciaService = ocorrenciaService;
        _tipoPontoSituacaoService = tipoPontoSituacaoService;
        _bus = bus;
        _moduloInterfacePortal = moduloInterfacePortal;
        _templateService = templateService;
    }

public ActionConfirmation SaveOrUpdate(PontoSituacao pontoSituacao)
    {
        return SaveOrUpdate(pontoSituacao, true, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ramaral conceitualmente dá para responder isto, neste momento a pergunta é conceitual. Se ele tiver um exemplo aí ela vira mais prática e pode ser melhor respondida.

Comment: Só com isto não temos como entender o todo e nem qual a dificuldade de instanciação. Dê mais detalhes do problema e se possível mais código que faça parte do problema. Deixe de lado todo o código que não ajude entender o problema, mas não deixa nada de fora que é importante para entendê-lo.

Comment: O problema é que quando eu vou instanciar a classe PontoSituacaoService pts = new PontoSituacaoService(); ele quer que eu passe todos os parametros, eu eu so quero usar método qlq que está a baixo do desse construtor, entendeu?

Comment: Não tem método algum abaixo do construtor.

Comment: é um metodo qualquer que esteja lá em baixo, eu pus o método SaveOrUpdate para vc ver, pronto quero instanciar e chama-lo(lembrando que essa classe tem "N" outros métodos implementados).

Comment: @vc_89 Esta classe me parece que foi feita para ser utilizada com injeção de depêndencia (contêiner IoC), e não ser instanciada na "mão" com `new`. Acho que sua dificuldade em instanciar esta classe seja por conta disto.

Comment: O conceito inicial é que eu preciso salvar em outra área(tabela) da minha aplicação chamada "Ponto de Situação" quando salvo por exemplo um formulário chamado "Movimentação População" e  nesse  formulário "Movimentação População"  o campo quantidade é maior que 20, portanto preciso usar a função saveorupdate.

Comment: Só acrescentando pessoal eu declarei um segundo construtor vazio na classe que eu queria instanciar, para que os parâmetros fossem opcionais, e funcionou. Obrigado a todos pela disponibilidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classe e interface são coisas bem distintas, ou é classe ou é interface. Classes e interfaces tem em comum que são tipos, só isso.

A instanciação de uma classe independe das interfaces que elas implementam (note que não usei o termo "herdam" que não é correto). É igual a qualquer caso. Nesse caso o problema é o construtor que exige que objetos sejam instanciados para criar o objeto. Até é necessário por causa das interfaces implementadas, mas isso é colateral.

Após a edição percebe-se uma classe extremamente complexa e que pode-se questionar se precisa disso tudo. Passa a impressão que está pegando algo pronto (tem cara de ser DDD) e que não entende o que está fazendo. Isso é um problema. Em coisas complexas assim precisa um grande domínio de programação, orientação a objeto, arquitetura, etc. Não use metodologias que não domina, não dá certo. Qualquer metodologia, boa ou ruim, só funciona quando a pessoa a domina. Por mais que uma metodologia possa ser maravilhosa, e muitas são mais marketing do que realidade, se não entender completamente como usá-la é pior que usar uma coisa mais básica. E essa parece ser bem complexa, tanto que talvez nem seja vantajosa para seu problema.

Eu até iria dizer que é preciso observar se é necessário implementar tantas interfaces assim nessa classe, ou até mesmo se esse método deveria fazer parte dessa classe. Se ele deve ser usado tão isoladamente assim, ou ele deveria ser estático, ou deveria fazer parte de outra classe. Mas parece que isso é uma questão de arquitetura.

Eu sou crítico à arquiteturas complexas, como essa. Esse é um exemplo muito claro do que eu sempre falo. Para consumir algo muito simples é necessário um código muito complexo. Me desculpe, mas esse código é uma atrocidade. Ele exige tanto para usá-lo que é melhor nem usar e fazer outra coisa, o que mataria o motivo de tê-lo criado.

Pior, pelo que entendi, o grosso desse objeto serve mais de controle da arquitetura do que do domínio do problema, e se for DDD seria irônico.

Sem mudar toda a arquitetura não tenho uma solução melhor, instancie o objeto com tudo o que ele exige e use o método que precisa em seguida. E sim, terá que criar pelo menos 7 objetos de classes que implementam essas interfaces só para consumir um método que talvez nem tenha relação com o que precisa.

Por outro lado pode estar fazendo tudo isso de forma tão errada que o problema esteja em outro lugar ou talvez não deva chamar este método que deseja e sim outra coisa. Pode ser que não deva chamar este método. A arquitetura pode ter essa classe para uso interno e não para seu consumo.

Se eu conhecesse o problema como um todo talvez dese para ajudar mais, mas esse problema resolve-se baixando a complexidade artificial da aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado eu entrei agora na empresa e isso é implementação antiga, eu não queria cometer nenhuma gafe do tipo repetir código, no entanto eu tbm tinha pensando instanciar passar todos os parametros que ele pede e depois usar só um método (das dezenas de métodos que essa  classe tem), mas isso que você falou sobre as arquiteturas me ajudou muito, obrigado mais uma vez.